# AWS SAM Authoring steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, aws-sam

I'm creating an a lambda function with AWS SAM that will receive a request, so some logic and return a presigned URL for the s3 bucket that the SAM template creates.
How can I create an athena dataset based on the bucket that is created in S3? I was hoping to do this in a separate repo to version control athena schema changes. Is this possible? Is there a way to create the athena schemas and have them applied by a CI job from within the SAM repo?

I was thinking I could create the s3 bucket outside of AWS SAM, but then I saw comments stating that lamda functions connecting the S3 Buckets outside of SAM is a bit of a hassle and requires some messing around to get this working. I might also want to read off of the s3 bucket stream for future development so I'm thinking it's better than SAM provisions the bucket. Just not sure how to connect Athena to the bucket programmatically so that a build job can deploy changes between the two projects.